# What is the prefix of an attached property that a subclass attaches

Tags: wpf, silverlight, attached-properties

I have been working with attached properties and came up with an interesting theoretical question. I know that if I want to set an attached property through XAML, I use the format:

```
<control ownerClass.propertyName="some value"/>
```

My question is, what happens if I derive a class from "ownerClass". For example, if I define the following class:

```
class MyGrid : Grid {
}
```

Tried to set it through XAML as follows

```
<MyGrid>
    <Button MyGrid.Row = "0">Bla Bla</Button>
</MyGrid>
```

But the intellisense did not let me. Once I used the proper namespace on the attached property, it worked.

Also, it allowed me to do this:

```
<MyGrid>
    <Button Grid.Row = "0">Bla Bla</Button>
</MyGrid>
```

It makes sense, of course, since the **Row** attached property is a static member of the **Grid** class and was defined by it. The only problem here is that the users of my new class get to know that it was derived from Grid, and that this specific property was defined by the ancestor. To me it seems like this is implementation details that I would not like to expose to the users of my class.

Is there a way to get WPF to **hide** the fact that this attached property was actually defined by the superclass?

Thanks,

Kobi

Comment: Just to clarify, Meleak have solved the original problem (thnx for that, Meleak), but I am still wondering if there is a way to "hide" the implementation details and not allow the user to access the attached property using the super class prefix. If, in the future, I decide to change the implementation so I do not use the Grid class as superclass, it should still work the same, so I would prefer that the users are not exposed to the fact that this class was inherited from the Grid class.

Comment: Do you want to hide Grid.Row from intellisence or do you want to disable the funtionality of Grid.Row or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I see the problem. I tried this out and it works. Also, the intellisence was working. What .NET version are you using and what version of VisualStudio? I tried this with .NET 4.0 and VS2010

```
<local:MyGrid>
    <local:MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </local:MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button local:MyGrid.Column="1" Content="Button1"/>
    <Button local:MyGrid.Column="0" Content="Button2"/>
</local:MyGrid>

public class MyGrid : Grid
{
    public MyGrid() { }
}
```

Comment: You are actually correct. It turned out I did not use the right namespace for the property itself.

Comment: Thanks :-). But I am still looking for a way to hide the "Grid.Row" possibility. I want the derived class to be used just like any other class, and would not like the attached properties to be accessed in 2 different ways just because I happen to derive my class from Grid instead of implementing it completely on my own. Do you happen to know of a way to do it?